# Typesafe play-oauth2-scala example

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe

I am trying to run [play-oauth2-scala](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/play-oauth2-scala)

But I am getting this conflict

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-fork-run-plugin;2.3.4: not found 
Failed to load project.
```

I am not sure why I am getting this issue

The Scala version I have is

```
Scala code runner version 2.11.7 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

The sbt version is 0.13.9

When it compiles I get this message

I tried adding in the build.sbt, but I am getting the same message, It does not find it.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `sbt-fork-run-plugin v 2.3.4` is not supported in typesafe http api anymore. Template seems to be outdated.

Solution: currently activator didn't have a proper solution but there is a work around,

1. Fetch a fresh version of template
2. Close all activators
3. edit `project/plugins.sbt` and `project/play-fork-run.sbt`, change play version

from `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.4")`

to   `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.10")`

Comment: Thank you @Hüseyin Zengin I edited your answer adding another file, but your answer was the key for find the solution.

Comment: I accepted your edit because it fits to your sitation better but; project/play-fork-run.sbt doesn't exists in template, sbt creates it so in a fresh fetched template there is no need to edit it because it doesn't exists, so thanks anyway :)